# PHP returning very odd $_POST results when using form arrays

Tags: php, html, forms, for-loop

Right, when users submit a form to update their contact information... odd things happen that make very little sense to me, and make it impossible for me to properly parse the resulting data.

The `$_POST` data sent to my script (found via `print_r`) is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [name_first] => Charles
    [name_last] => Broughton
    [company] => 
    [address1] => 
    [address2] => 
    [city] => Bristol
    [region] => England
    [postal] => 
    [country] => 1
    [email] => *******************
    [phones_types] => Array
        (
            [0] => Cell
        )

    [phones_numbers] => Array
        (
            [0] => ************
        )

    [phone_types] => Array
        (
            [1] => Home
        )

    [phone_numbers] => Array
        (
            [1] => ************
        )

    [pass] => **********
    [id] => 
)
```

The form creating this odd output is as follows:

```
<form action="URL" method="POST">
  <table class="data" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tbody>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">Edit Contact</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>First Name:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="name_first" value="Charles"/> (required)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Last Name:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="name_last" value="Broughton"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Company:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="company" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Address Line 1:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="address1" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Address Line 2:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="address2" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>City:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="city" value="Bristol"/> (required)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Region:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="region" value="England"/> (required)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Postal:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="postal" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Country:</td>
      <td><select name="country">
        <option value="1" selected="selected">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="2">United States</option>
      </select> (required)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="email" value="*******************"/> (required)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Phones(s):</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="phones_types[0]" value="Cell"/>: <input type="text" name="phones_numbers[0]" value="************"/><br/><input type="text" name="phone_types[1]"/>: <input type="text" name="phone_numbers[1]"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Current Password:</td>
      <td><input type="password" name="pass"/> (required)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Save Changed"/></td>
    </tr>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value=""/>
  </tbody></table>
</form>
```

Does anybody know how I can remedy this, or parse it properly using PHP?  I tried a `for` loop to parse both arrays as one, but neither of them are arrays due to the separation... the example of which is in the above `print_r` output.

--

**EDIT** I was attempting to parse the form data using the following bit of PHP, with the proceeding error message being outputted.

```
if (count($_POST['phone_types'])!=0 && count($_POST['phone_numbers'])!=0)
{
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['phone_types']); $i++)
  {
    if (!empty($_POST['phone_types'][$i]) && !empty($_POST['phone_numbers'][$i]))
      $phones[$_POST['phone_types'][$i]] = $_POST['phone_numbers'][$i];
  }
  $ph = "";
  foreach ($phones as $k => $v)
  {
    $ph.= "$k:$v;";
  }
  $phones = $ph;
}
else
  $phones = "";
```

Error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for `foreach()` in `FILE` on line 35
```

Comment: what are you expecting?   that is what was posted if you do not change anything

Comment: I entered a second phone number and second type in the form when submitting it, and instead of getting two arrays of [0] => number, [1] => number... they are two different sets of two arrays due to... form input order I'm guessing?  But then PHP doesn't understand it at all.

Comment: looks fine to me :/ what's the problem?

Comment: you have the namings of the inputs wrong (one is prural and one is singular) - if I understood your problem...

Comment: @cdbroughton -- use `[]` instead of `[0], [1], ...`

Comment: @hex4 -- turned your comment into an answer.

Comment: I did the [#] to try and fix this, it was [] before; and it would create two sets of arrays with index 0 set to the values expected :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="phones_types[0]" value="Cell"/>: 
<input type="text" name="phones_numbers[0]" value="************"/><br/>
<input type="text" name="phone_types[1]"/>: 
<input type="text" name="phone_numbers[1]"/>
```

should be:

```
<input type="text" name="phones_types[0]" value="Cell"/>: 
<input type="text" name="phones_numbers[0]" value="************"/><br/>
<input type="text" name="phones_types[1]"/>: 
<input type="text" name="phones_numbers[1]"/>
```

in order to be able to loop the phones_types & phones_number using a foreach

Comment: Wow, I can't beleive I didn't see that.

Answer (score 2):

You're using array notation in the input fields: `phones_types[0]` indicates to PHP that it should create a `phones_types` array, and this particularly field should be element 0 in it.

Any form field with `[]` at the end of its name is treated by PHP as a directive to treat it as an array, so you can submit multiple values to the same 'name'.

Comment: I am aware of this, but it is creating a single array PER index, I'm guessing because of the order of inputs on the form.  Which means when I do a `for` or `foreach` on it.... the output does not have two indexes, but only one instead.

Comment: then why not just change it to [] instead of indexed versions? Should work properly anyway

Answer (score 1):

Field names that have brackets in them are automatically converted to arrays by PHP. If you are having problems with missing array entries, try changing `[0]` to `[]` in your field names.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays.

Comment: I am aware of this, but it is creating a single array PER index, I'm guessing because of the order of inputs on the form.  Which means when I do a `for` or `foreach` on it.... the output does not have two indexes, but only one instead.

Answer (score 0):

One of your posts is for `phones_numbers` and the other is for `phone_numbers`

Those **do no match** so they will be separate `_POST` values